# Simple Javascript rule to remove div if contentheight < 500

Tags: javascript, css, html, resize, image-resizing

I'm looking for a JS rule that removes a div if contentheight < 500

I've gotten the following working for an image but need to replace the image resize with a command to remove a div:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  

 function imageresize() {  
 var contentheight = $('#maincontainer').height();  
 if ((contentheight) < '500'){  
 $('.fluidimage').attr('src','images/big-sm.jpg');  
 } else {  
 $('.fluidimage').attr('src','images/big.jpg');  
 }  
 }  

 imageresize();//Triggers when document first loads      

 $(window).bind("resize", function(){//Adjusts image when browser resized  
 imageresize();  
 });  

 });
```

All help greatly appreciated

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried? This is a pretty simple task to accomplish, and [the jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/) readily provide the information you need here.

Comment: How does the div grow? Is there an input element withing it?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery removing a `div` or any DOM element is simply `$(selector).remove();`
Is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 function imageresize() {  
    var contentheight = $('#maincontainer').height();  
    if (contentheight < 500){
        $('.fluidimage').attr('src','images/big-sm.jpg');  
    } else {  
        $('.fluidimage').attr('src','images/big.jpg');  
    }  
 }
 imageresize(); //Triggers when document first loads      
 $(window).bind("resize", function(){
     //Adjusts image when browser resized  
     imageresize();  
 });
});
```

`500` is a number, not a string. It should not be in quotes.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eSBUz/

Answer (score 0):

What about using each to iterate over the divs and check the dimension ? doing that you have the reference of the DIV on each call. something like this :

```
$(".box").each(function (index) {
    console.log( $(this).attr("width") );
    w = Number( $(this).attr("width") );
    if( w > 10 ){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hamiltonlima/dDJcA/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Venugopal/eSBUz/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
function imageresize() {  
var contentheight = $('#maincontainer').height();  
if (contentheight < 250){
    $('#maincontainer').css('background','blue');  
} else {  
    $('#maincontainer').css('background','red');
}  
}
imageresize(); //Triggers when document first loads      
$(window).bind("resize", function(){
 //Adjusts image when browser resized  
 imageresize();  
 });
});
```

Comment: Hi there, this works great for adding or removing css elements within a div but what if I want to remove an entire id? Thanks for the help - much appreciated

Comment: Thanks Venu - got it sorted :)